# SAS Call define is not assigning the URL

Tags: sas

I'm trying to assign a dynamic URL with call define, but it is not working.
Here is the initial table with URLs. There will be individual URLs for every entry.

Here is my code:

```
Data teams_link;
    set Teams;
    link = "https://www.google.com/";
run;

ods html;

Proc report data = teams_link;
    columns Team_A Team_B link;

    define Team_A /"Team A";
    define Team_B /"Team B";
    define link /"URL";

    compute Team_A;
        call define (_col_, 'url', link);
    endcomp;

    compute Team_B;
        call define (_col_, 'url', "https://www.google.com/");
    endcomp;

run;
```

Here is the result:
[image]

URL gets assigned to "Team B", but not to "Team A". Why is that and how to make it work?

What I tried so far:

- Wrapping URL in single and double quotes in compute statement.
- Creating a variable within compute statement, assigning URL to is, and then putting that variable in call define statement.
- Removing any possible spaces with compress function.

I'm out of options now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PROC REPORT processes the variables in the order they appear in the COLUMNS statement. So when the COMPUTE block for TEAM_A runs the value of LINK is empty.

Move the variable LINK before TEAM_A in the COLUMN statement. You can use an alias to reference the same input variable more than once.  You can use NOPRINT on the extra one to prevent it from printing.

```
proc report data = teams_link;
    columns link=link_a Team_A Team_B link;

    define link_a / noprint;
    define Team_A /"Team A";
    define Team_B /"Team B";
    define link /"URL";

    compute Team_A;
        call define (_col_, 'url', link_a);
    endcomp;

    compute Team_B;
        call define (_col_, 'url', "https://www.google.com/");
    endcomp;

run;
```